# Get souce code of current Facebook's page using Google Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I want to make a extension in chrome to view source code of current page use it (in this case is Facebook page). I already get the current url and then pass it into function to get source code. But the source code I get doesn't same with when I use View page source of Chrome browser. I trying to debug, but it didn't have any bug or problem, neither warning. I so confuse don't know why.

The HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>   
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="host"></div>
      <div id="sourcex"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JS file:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tabs){     
       var currentURL = tabs[0].url;
       window.onload = function getSourceCode() {
           var b = currentURL;
           var url = b, xmlhttp;//Remember, same domain
           if ("XMLHttpRequest" in window)
               xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           if ("ActiveXObject" in window)
               xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
           xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                   var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
                   var c = String(a);
                   document.getElementById('sourcex').innerHTML = c;
               }
           };
           xmlhttp.send();
       }  
   }
);
```

The manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "2.0",

  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "cookies",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
    "management",
    "http://facebook.com/",
    "https://facebook.com/",
        "downloads"
    ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*"
    ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"

}
```

Comment: javascript can change a lot on a website, the "view source" function in the browser only shows what you get from the server.

Comment: side note: why include jquery if you don´t even use it for ajax? you really don´t need jquery anymore. i suggest taking a look at the native fetch api.

Comment: Sorry I forgot i clear include jquery. Does have any way to get the source code by using javascript like View page source?

Comment: That is not directly possible, no. You would have to make an additional AJAX request to get the source code.